# How to run this with out spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to spring and maven, i do have this app which is referring from, https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
I am using spring + maven.

I need to get the output into a simple html via tomcat, currently it is using embedded Apache Tomcat 7.

```
    package hello;

public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}


package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

This is the main which uses spring boot, to run in embedded Apache.

```
    package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with this! What i need is simple web service without embedded tomcat. just need normal tomcat deploying.

pom.xml is as bellow.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: add your pom.xml in the post. Where does it specify that you are using embedded tomcat.

Comment: How to do that is explained in the Spring Boot [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) and there is [this guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/).

Answer (score -1):

Add This to your POM

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

and do `mvn install` or `mvn package`

You will see in your target folder the artifact ending with xxx.war.original. That one can be deployed straight into Tomcat.

edit:- Update as per comments below. Following changes needs to be made as well.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Refer [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) for more details as cited in the comments section.

Comment: but is this a embedded tomcat enabled project. I don't see any tomcat-maven plugin in pom.xml.

Comment: mvn install success, server running but not working, HTTP Status 404 - /greeting

Comment: The pom.xml is inheriting from `spring-boot-starter-parent` using the `<parent>` tag. So the embedded tomcat is inherited. If you have eclipse open your pom.xml for any spring boot project and click on the 'Effective POM' tab and you can see the tomcat-maven-plugin

Comment: The tomcat-maven-plugin has nothing to do with packaging as a war.

Comment: This is insufficient. The correct steps to follow are described in the reference documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

Answer (score -1):

**Perfect Solution and code to your Question**

1. SpringBoot contains Embedded Tomcat, Hence there is no special configuration required in your POM.xml
2. Your POM.xml should like this below code. I have used bootsample as an artifact and hence rest are all same.

   ```
                        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
                       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                       <groupId>com.yourcompany.app</groupId>
                       <artifactId>bootsample</artifactId>
                       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                       <packaging>war</packaging>
                       <parent>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                   <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
                       </parent>

                       <dependencies>
                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                   </dependency>


                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                   </dependency>
                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                       <scope>provided</scope>
                   </dependency>
                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                       <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                       <optional>true</optional>
                   </dependency>
               </dependencies>
               <build>
                   <finalName>bootsample</finalName>
                   <plugins>
                       <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                           <configuration>
                               <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                               <layout>ZIP</layout>
                           </configuration>
                           <executions>
                               <execution>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>repackage</goal>
                                   </goals>
                               </execution>
                           </executions>
                       </plugin>


                       <plugin>

                           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                           <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                           <configuration>
                               <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                           </configuration>
                       </plugin>
                   </plugins>
               </build>

               <repositories>
                   <repository>
                       <id>spring-releases</id>
                       <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
                   </repository>
               </repositories>
               <pluginRepositories>
                   <pluginRepository>
                       <id>spring-releases</id>
                       <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
                   </pluginRepository>
               </pluginRepositories>
           </project>
           </project>
   ```
3. Your Greeting Domain Object.

   ```
       /**
    * 
    */


   import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

   /**
    * @author Praveen
    *
    */
   @Component
   public class Greeting {

       private final long id;
       private final String content;

       public Greeting(long id, String content) {
           this.id = id;
           this.content = content;
       }

       public long getId() {
           return id;
       }

       public String getContent() {
           return content;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Your Controller, Before careful you have use **@ResponseBody** annotation, else you will get circularpath ViewResolver Exception, because SpringBoot sets default viewResolver. This **@ResponseBody annotation** will **skip** your ViewResolver problems.

   ```
                       /**
                    * 
                    */

                   import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

                   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
                   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
                   import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
                   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
                   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
                   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
                   /**
                    * @author Praveen
                    *
                    */
                   @Controller
                   @EnableAutoConfiguration
                   @ResponseBody
                   //@ComponentScan
                   public class SimpleController {
                       private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
                       private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
                       @RequestMapping("/greeting")

                       public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
                           return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                                               String.format(template, name));
                       }



                       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

                           SpringApplication.run(SimpleController.class, args);
                       }
                   }
   ```
5. Please use the Maven Goals as indicated in below figure.
   Your maven goals should be **mvn clean package spring-boot:run -e**
   [image: Maven Goals for Spring Boot]
6. Once you execute this, your embedded tomcat will run and you can find your successful output. [image]
7. Successful Log 
   [image: Successful Log]
8. Additionally you can refer this link [Spring-boot reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/). for your WAR/JAR creation questions.

Comment: The OP is asking how to deploy a Spring Boot application as a war to Tomcat. This is describing how to run a Spring Boot application in Eclipse using Maven and `spring-boot:run`

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to answer the question. You've wasted a lot of time here. Your edits (8) are unacceptable on SO. Please read [ask] and [answer].